# How to mockup data of table using react testing library in react 17?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to write the test cases for mockup data of the table. Following are the sample snippets of files.

```js
import {Grid, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow} from '@material-ui/core';

export const renderTableData = (item) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} className={classes.tableContianer}>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow classes={{root: classes.tableRow}}>
            {item.columns &&
              item.columns.map((subItem, index) => {
                return (
                  <TableCell padding="none" key={index}>
                    {subItem}
                  </TableCell>
                );
              })}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {item.rows.map((row, index) => (
            <TableRow key={index} classes={{root: classes.tableRow}}>
              {Object.keys(row).map((key, index) => {
                return (
                  <TableCell padding="none" key={index} classes={{root: classes.tableCell}}>
                    {row[key]}
                  </TableCell>
                );
              })}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

And here is my sample test files for the test cases

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import {renderTableData} from "./Table"

 it('renders without crashing', async () => { 
    
    const props = {
        
        columns:['one','two','three','four'],
        rows:[{one:"onedata",two:"twodata",three:"threedata",four:"fourdata"}]
    }
    render(<renderTable props={props}/>)
    screen.debug();
 }
```

when I am running the test cases of this files and check the console because of the screen.debug() ,it only shows me the props ={object object} rather it should render the html view of the files but I can not get it.
Could some one take a look and let me know what should I modify the code to render the table with data into the screen.debug().

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`props ={object object}` is correct because you're passing an object.

If you want to see the contents, try `JSON.stringify(props)`

Not sure if you're trying to console.log your props or display on screen

```
<div>
    { JSON.stringify(props) }
</div>
```

To view the debug, you'll need to destructure debug from the render

```
const { debug } = render(<renderTable props={props}/>);
debug();
```

[See this example](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#debug)

Sample component...

```
onst Content = ({props}) => {
    return (
        <div
            data-qa="content"
            className={styles.container}
        >
            {
                JSON.stringify(props)
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default Content;
```

In your test...

```
            const { debug } = render(
                <Content props={{
                    columns:['one','two','three','four'],
                    rows:[{one:"onedata",two:"twodata",three:"threedata",four:"fourdata"}]
                }} />,
            )
            debug();
```

Output in terminal...

```
  Content
    Component Elements
      ✓ should ... (23ms)

  console.log node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:93
    <body>
      <div>
        <div
          data-qa="content"
        >
          {"columns":["one","two","three","four"],"rows":[{"one":"onedata","two":"twodata","three":"threedata","four":"fourdata"}]}
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: but screen.debug should show all the header and data

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good choice to test data table using RTL. Try jest instead.